# Django merge 2 querysets overide annotation

Tags: django, annotations

I have 2 models.
Followers
Influencers

```
class Influencer(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"), max_length=250, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Follower", verbose_name=_("Followers"))
```

I want to create a QS of followers from 2 influencers:

```
influencer_choosen_by_user = [influ1name, influ2name]

qs = Follower.objects.none()
qs_influencers = Influencer.objects.filter(username__in=influencer_choosen_by_user)
for influencer_obj in qs_influencers.iterator():
    followers_of_influ_qs = influencer_obj.followers.all()  # get all followers of this influencer
    followers_of_influ_qs = followers_of_influ_qs.annotate(
        influencer_source=Value(f'followers/{influencer_obj.username}', CharField()))
    qs = qs | followers_of_influ_qs
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

qs = <[followers1,influ1name] , [followers2, influ2name], [followers3, influ2name]>

NOTE:

A follower can follow many influencers

ISSUE:

All qs are of **influencer_source == influ1name** none of influ2name !!!

**Why ?**

Comment: Normally using strin literals does not belong in the query. You can annotate the `Influencer` objects and annotate these with the number of followers

Comment: This looks more like something that belongs in the template to render the followers of a username.

Comment: Can you explain *what* you aim to do, not *how*. Likely a better solution exists than to iterate over the `Influencer` objects.

Comment: added EXPECTED RESULTS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the followers with an extra attribute that determines the username of that `Influencer` with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Follower.objects.filter(
    influencer__username__in=influencer_choosen_by_user
).annotate(
    influencer=F('influencer__username')
)
```

In that case the `Follower` objects will have an extra attribute `.influencer` which contains the username of the influencer. If a follower follows multiple influencers, the follower will occur twice or more in the queryset, each time with `.influencer` another username of the `influencer_choosen_by_user`.

Comment: But I don't want to have multiple influencers  - only those in influencer_choosen_by_user. should I remove them after ? I have Millions of raws here any action can take time.

Comment: @flicecom: that is exactly what happens,; it will only retrun the followrs that follow the influencers, and only if the follower follows multiple influendcers from the `influencer_choose_by_user`, it will return multiple ones, one per `influencer_choose_by_user` that is a follower.

Comment: @flicecom: in other words, we first filter the related `Infuencer` model to only retain influencers that we want to see, and then of those we see, we will add a `Follower` record per `Influencer` we are *interested* in, not *all* (global) influencers.

Comment: Can you explain the first issue ? I still want to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: @flicecom: OR (`|`) only will make an OR for the conditions, it will not look for annotations (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#or). Perhaps `qs = qs.union(qs2)` produces better results, but regardless how, the implementation results in cursors and more database queries than necessary.

Comment: I dont understand how's this method will not return rows of qs with influencers not in influencer_choosen_by_user. i mean influencer_choosen_by_user can contain 2 but a follower can follow 50 - will I have 1/2 record or up to 50 ?

Comment: @flicecom: the `.filter(influencer__username__in=influencer_choosen_by_user)` will remove all influencers from the table that we will join with, and thus these are not part of the `.annotate(influencer=F('influencer__username'))`. `.filter(..)` thus has effect on the next `.annotate(...)`s, etc.

Comment: If you thus filter with `.filter(influencer__username__in=influencer_choosen_by_user)` and a `Follower` follows 50 items, but the `influencer_choose_by_user` contains two items, then that `Follower` will be retrieved *at most* two times. It can be zero if it does not follow any of the two, one if it follows one of the two, and two if it follows both.

Comment: Thanks ! still don't you think it is a bug that or operation on QS override the annotations ?

Comment: how to remove duplicated most effective ? .distinct() don't worl since the influencer is different.

Comment: @flicecom: if the influencer is not relevant, you simply remove the `.annotate(..)` caluse, and then use `.distinct()`, but in your question you want the follower together with the influencer, so I do not understand why you now want a distinct set.

Comment: @flicecom: I would not see this as a bug, this is more "unspecified" behavior. As a result, even if that would have worked, it was merely an implementation detail, and thus not a good idea.